# Showing the intersection of two expressions

Tags: graph, 3d, maple, intercept

I try to plot 3D graph on Maple18. I plot 2 graphs on the same plane and I want it to show all intercepts. I actually want only integral intercepts if it's possible but I don't know the command.
Here is the graph I want it to show the intercepts

plot3d([x^2, 3^6*z-432], x = -50 .. 50, z = 0 .. 20)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in just showing the intersection of the two expressions, you might try the [plots:-intersectplot](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plots%2Fintersectplot) command. The following will show the intersection for the two surfaces:

```
p1 := plots:-intersectplot(y=x^2, y=3^6*z-432, x=-50..50, z=0..20, y=0..14000);
```

If you want to then superimpose this on your original plot:

```
p2 := plot3d([x^2, 3^6*z-432], x=-50..50, z=0..20):
plots:-display([p1,p2]);
```